# Slight challenge. Need to optimize code. Original one takes too long :(

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, csv, bar-chart

So i'm trying to read 3 different csv files and plotting the information in an img with four graphs.
One with the average delay by airline, expressed in minutes
Another with the ratio of delayed flights, by airline
Another with the average delay by destination airport, expressed in minutes
And finally another with the ratio of flights delayed to arrival, by destination airport

All the information is correct and i got it from the files. The problem is that the program below takes too long to produce the graphs and that they're all being separately plotted and not all together in one image. Is there a way to optimize my code to run faster? And how do i use subplots without changing everything?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path_main = '850566403_T_ONTIME.csv'
path_airline = 'L_AIRLINE_ID.csv'
path_airport = 'L_AIRPORT_ID.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(path_main)
al = pd.read_csv(path_airline)
ap = pd.read_csv(path_airport)

#remove columns and rows with nan
df1.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
df = df1.dropna(subset=['ARR_DELAY_NEW'])
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Airlines:

#dict with {ID: Name}
d_al = {}
for i in range(len(al)):
    d_al[al['Code'][i]] = al['Description'][i]

# array with ID's of airlines and delays
arr_al = df.loc[:, ('AIRLINE_ID', 'ARR_DELAY_NEW')].to_numpy()

# list with ID's of airlines
list_al = []
for i in arr_al:
    if i[0] not in list_al:
        list_al.append(int(i[0]))

def airline_avg_ratio(ID):
    '''
    function that requires an airline ID
    and returns a tuple with name (first 10
    characters), average delay and
    delayed flight ratios
    '''   
    nr_voos = 0
    soma = 0
    nr_atrasos = 0
    for i in arr_al:
        if i[0] == ID:
            soma += i[1]
            nr_voos += 1
            if i[1] != 0:
                nr_atrasos += 1
    for k,v in d_al.items():
        if k == ID:
            nome = v[0:10]
    media = round((soma / nr_atrasos), 3)
    racio = round((nr_atrasos / nr_voos), 3)
    return (nome, media, racio)


dados_al = []
for i in list_al:
    dados_al.append(airline_avg_ratio(i))
    
df_al = pd.DataFrame(dados_al, columns=['Airlines', 'Average', 'Ratio'])

graph1 = df_al.drop(columns='Ratio').sort_values(by='Average').iloc[-10:]
graph1.plot(x='Airlines', y='Average', kind='bar')
plt.title("Atraso Médio por Companhia (top 10)")
plt.xlabel('Companhia Aérea', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Minutos', fontsize=12)
plt.show()

graph2 = df_al.drop(columns='Average').sort_values(by='Ratio').iloc[-10:]
graph2.plot(x='Airlines', y='Ratio', kind='bar')
plt.title("Vôos Atrasados por Companhia (top 10)")
plt.xlabel('Companhia Aérea', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Rácio', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Airports:
    
#dict with {ID: Name}
d_ap = {}
for i in range(len(ap)):
    d_ap[ap['Code'][i]] = ap['Description'][i]

#array with ID's of Airports and delays
arr_ap = df.loc[:, ('DEST_AIRPORT_ID', 'ARR_DELAY_NEW')].to_numpy()


#list with ID's of Airports
list_ap = []
for i in arr_ap:
    if i[0] not in list_ap:
        list_ap.append(int(i[0]))

def airport_avg_ratio(ID):
    '''
    function that requires an airport
    and returns a tuple with name (first 10
    characters), average delay and
    delayed flight ratios
    '''   
    nr_chegadas = 0
    soma = 0
    nr_atrasos = 0
    for i in arr_ap:
        if i[0] == ID:
            soma += i[1]
            nr_chegadas += 1
            if i[1] != 0:
                nr_atrasos += 1
    for k,v in d_ap.items():
        if k == ID:
            nome = v[0:10]
    media = round((soma / nr_atrasos), 3)
    racio = round((nr_atrasos / nr_chegadas), 3)
    return (nome, media, racio)

dados_ap = []
for i in list_ap:
    dados_ap.append(airport_avg_ratio(i))
    
df_ap = pd.DataFrame(dados_ap, columns=['Airports', 'Average', 'Ratio'])

graph3 = df_ap.drop(columns='Ratio').sort_values(by='Average').iloc[-10:]
graph3.plot(x='Airports', y='Average', kind='bar')
plt.title("Atraso Médio por Aeroporto (top 10)")
plt.xlabel('Aeroporto', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Minutos', fontsize=12)
plt.show()

graph4 = df_ap.drop(columns='Average').sort_values(by='Ratio').iloc[-10:]
graph4.plot(x='Airports', y='Ratio', kind='bar')
plt.title("Vôos Atrasados por Aeroporto (top 10)")
plt.xlabel('Aeroporto', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Rácio', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: have you indentified which part of this takes too long?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. In order to improve your question it could be helpful to focus on a single problem: you may want to the find bottleneck in your code and limit your question to it. Try to post [minimal but complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without looking too much into it: Your code would likely run faster if you ran vectorized operation on the whole pandas dataframe, instead of iterating over it in a for-loop -- just a guess tho